# AttributeError: type object 'TestPages' has no attribute 'test_sort_by_price'

Tags: python, unit-testing, automation, ddt

For some reason I can't run ddt.py. Could you explain what is the problem? In official documentation it looks like this.

```
@ddt
class TestPages(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    @file_data('client.json')
    def test_sort_by_price(self, value):
        print("\n" + str(test_cases(2)))
        gallerypage = GalleryPage(self.driver, value)
        result = gallerypage.sort_by_price()
        self.assertTrue(result)
```

ERROR:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
    raise self._exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 168, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: type object 'TestPages' has no attribute 'test_sort_by_price'
```

Comment: I import this way `from ddt import ddt, file_data`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you run separate test, not the test class itself. Try to run test class, it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

first, rename `ddt.py` to `test_dtt.py` to avoid confusion of lib

second, `find . -name "*dtt*.py*"`, rename them properly

last, find and remove any `*.pyc` files and rerun the tests

```
for file in `find . -name "*.pyc"`; do rm -vf $file; done
```